Ubuntu 24.10 Oracular Oriole
When Ubuntu 24.10 Oracular Oriole is coming out? We in October already! What's new in Ubuntu 24.10? Thank you!
Ubuntu 24.10 Oracular Oriole

When released as per schedule (which isn't yet!)   If you want to view the status, go look at the status page, or view the ISO/QA tracker page for oracular and you can see the various teams flag themselves as "ready".... You can watch various IRC/matrix rooms & get a rather accurate clue (as to actual time too) if you know the process that is followed, as everything is done according to set & documented procedures....

For details on what is new with Ubuntu 24.10, please refer to the release notes
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/oracular-oriole-release-notes/44878
To review status, you can view the status page
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/oracular-oriole-24-10-release-status-tracking/48269
There are also other ways of viewing detail too, eg. the ISO QA tracker allows you to see when different teams declare they're READY  (look for bold and (ready))
https://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/463/builds
For more, given all releases occur as per a documented process, you can just watch conversations in the various IRC/matrix rooms too; everything is very predictable in order, given the Ubuntu Release team follow their procedures.

I've voted this question as off-topic; I'm sure its been asked before (and gets asked almost every release; esp. LTS releases) but I failed to find a duplicate..   I'm happy to delete this answer (it's of little value as I see it, doesn't solve a problem) but the problem maybe only an itch that can be easily scratched with this type of detail, which hopefully will encourage enthusiasm & other good things...    I could have given more too, but distracted with other things (we're approaching a release..)

I think this is a very good answer to a common question.
